# Unexpected output from rollapply due to zero length output from the function

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

I'm encountering a problem that I'm failling to understand. Here is the commented code :

```
library(zoo)
#Pattern p used as row feeding matrix to apply() for function f
> p
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1

#Function f supposed to take rows of matrix p as vectors,
#compare them with vector x and return index
f <- function(x) {  # identifies which row of `patterns` matches sign(x)
  which(apply(p,1,function(row)all(row==sign(x))))
}

#rollapplying f over c(1,-1,1,1) : there is no vector c(1,-1,1) in p
#so why the first atom is 1 ?
> rollapply(c(1,-1,1,1),width=3,f,align="left")
[1] 1 1

#rollapply identity, rollapply is supposed to feed row to the function right ?
> t = rollapply(c(1,-1,1,1),width=3,function(x)x,align="left")
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   -1    1
[2,]   -1    1    1

#Feeding the first row of the precedent matrix to f is giving the expected result
> f(t[1,])
integer(0)

#rollapply feeds the rolls to the function
> rollapply(c(1,-1,1,1),width=3,function(x) paste(x,collapse=","),align="left")
[1] "1,-1,1" "-1,1,1"

#rollapply feeds vectors to the function
> rollapply(c(1,-1,1,1),width=3,function(x) is.vector(x),align="left")
[1] TRUE TRUE

#Unconsistent with the 2 precedent results
> f(c(1,-1,1))
integer(0)
```

Basically I don't understand why `rollapply(c(1,-1,1,1),width=3,f,align="left")` is returning `1 1` when the first roll from `rollapply` is supposed to yield the vector `1 -1 1` that is absent from the pattern matrix `p`. I was expecting the result `NA 1` instead. There must be something I don't understand about `rollapply` but strangely enough if I feed the vector `c(-1, -1, -1 ,-1)` to `rollapply` I get the expected result `NA NA`. In some cases I have a mix `1 2` but never a mix `NA 1` or `NA 2`.

Comment: Can you make the question title a bit more informative? Something along the lines of "expecting 1 -1 1 but get 1 1 from rollapply".

Comment: I'm guessing wildly that `rollapply` doesn't "like" an output of zero length (i.e. `integer(0)`) and is backfilling that value.

Comment: Yes, `rollapply` does not support functions producing zero length outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to G. Grothendieck rollapply does not support functions producing zero length outputs. It is possible to get rid of the problem by adding a condition in the function `f` returning a specific output in case it was returning zero length output.

```
  f <- function(x) {  # identifies which row of `patterns` matches sign(x)
    t <- which(apply(patterns,1,function(row)all(row==sign(x))))
    ifelse(length(t)==0, return(0), return(t))
  }
```

Comment: FYI - @G.Grothendieck is an auther of `zoo`, so his is the definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, quoting GGrothendieck's comment.  "rollapply does not support functions producing zero length outputs. "   That is consistent with the behavior below.

Further confusion, at least for me (this should be a comment but I wanted some decent formatting):

`sfoo<-c(1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1)
rollapply(sfoo,width=3,function(j){k<-f(j);print(j);return(k)})
[1]  1 -1  1
[1] -1  1  1
[1] 1 1 1
[1]  1  1 -1
[1]  1 -1  1
[1] -1  1  1
[1] 1 2 1 1 2 1`

I then tried:

```
ff<-function(x) which(rowSums(p)==sum(x))
sbar<-c(0,1,1,1,-1,0,-1)
rollapply(sbar,width=3,function(j){k<-ff(j);print(j);return(k)})
[1] 0 1 1
[1] 1 1 1
[1]  1  1 -1
[1]  1 -1  0
[1] -1  0 -1
[1] 2 1 2 1 2
```

Which sure looks like `rollapply` is doing a `na.locf`-sort of filling in operation.